# Automapping error: The type does not have a default constructor

Tags: c#, linq, mapping, expression, automapper

I'm running into an error when I try to map a persistence object to a domain model which does not have a default constructor.

```
public class SetupGroup {

    public List<CameraDisplayMap> Mappings { get; set; }

}

public class CameraDisplayMap {

    public Camera Camera { get; private set; }
    public Display Display { get; private set; }

    public CameraDisplayMap(Camera camera, Display display)
        ...

}
```

#### Repository

```
public IEnumerable<CameraDisplayMap> GetSetupGroupMappings(int setupGroupId) {

    return ((IQueryable<SetupGroupPto> GetAll())
        .Where(x => x.Id == setupGroupId)
        .Select(x => x.Mappings) // returns CameraDisplayMapPto from SetupGroupPto
        .Project()
        .To<CameraDisplayMap>();
}
```

I've already tried registering this using mapping configurations...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CameraDisplayMapPto, CameraDisplayMap>()
            .ConstructUsing(x => new CameraDisplayMap(x.Camera, x.Display));
```

...with both using .ConstructUsing() and .ConvertUsing(), but it seams this doesn't work with the automapper projections.

Stack:

```
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) <---
at [..].ProjectionExpression`1.BuildExpression[TDest]()
```

Comment: Have you tried anything like this? https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters create class implementing `ITypeConverter<>` then in the convert method, construct your object then return it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bogard, you rock! The most recent version of Automapper now supports projection conversions:

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/12/23/automapper-3-3-feature-projection-conversions/

For anyone stumbling upon this, as of Version 3.3 of Automapper, you
can declare the projection conversions like so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CameraDisplayMapPto, CameraDisplayMap>()
      ---->   .ConstructProjectionUsing(x => new CameraDisplayMap(x.Camera, x.Display));
```

Comment: Ha, thanks! Though I think this should be automatically supported. Looking at the code, the expression pieces don't respect constructor parameter mappings. I created a GH issue for this: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/654